# child class method pointer to method parent argument c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods, arguments

it might be strange what i'm trying to see and i will try to clarify as much as possible. I'm using gcc 4.8 on ubuntu 14.04 and C++11.

What i want trying to do is:

- make a class A
- make a function in that class A which gets as argument
- a pointer to a class member of the same class
- make a new class B which inherits from A
- make a new method of class B
- give a pointer to that method of class B to a method of parentclass A as argument

  ```
  class A{
      typedef void(A::*METHOD);        

      void executeMethod(METHOD arg){};
  }

  class B : A{

      void sampleMethod(){};

      void childMethod(){              

        this->executeMethod(&B::sampleMethod); //<== error
      }
  }
  ```

However this brings me the following error in codeblocks:

```
error: no matching function to call for 'B::executeMethod(void B::*)'
```

Is there any way around this?
Is there anything else i need to do to make it clear to you, what i'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly call child method from a base class, but you can use template:

```
class A {
public:
    template<class T>
    void executeMethod( void (T::*method)() )
    {
        (static_cast<T *>( this )->*method)();
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void sampleMethod() {}
    void childMethod() { executeMethod( &B::sampleMethod ); }
};
```

But more flexible solution would be to use `std::function` and `std::bind` as then you can pass methods which signature does not match.

```
class A {
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> Method;

    void executeMethod( const Method &method )
    {
        method();
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void sampleMethod1() {}
    void sampleMethod2( int param ) {}

    void childMethod1() { executeMethod( std::bind( &B::sampleMethod1, this ); }
    void childMethod2() { executeMethod( std::bind( &B::sampleMethod2, this, 123 ); }
};
```

Comment: typedef std::function<void()> Method; gives me error: 'function' does not name a type

Comment: @philsegeler you need to include `<functional>`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `sampleMethod` isn't a member of `A`, it's a member of `B` and can't convert to a `void(A::*)`.

Did you consider using virtual methods perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef void(A::*METHOD);
```

defines `METHOD` to be a pointer of type `void*` to a member variable of `A`, not a pointer to a member function of `A`.

You need:

```
typedef void (A::*METHOD)();
```

Even with that change, you can't use a member function of `B` to pass as an argument where `METHOD` is expected.

You can make the function that you want to pass a virtual member function of `A` and use it.

```
class A {
   protected:
      typedef void(A::*METHOD)();        

      void executeMethod(METHOD arg){};

   public:
      virtual void sampleMethod() = 0;
};

class B : public A {

   virtual void sampleMethod(){};

   void childMethod(){              

      this->executeMethod(&A::sampleMethod);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a callable object bound to a member function you should use std::bind. This will create a forwarding wrapper which will call sampleMethod with some of its parameters pre specified. In this case, the "this" parameter will be bound.

std::bind(&B::sampleMethod, this);

Comment: First of all OP does not need a function pointer, he asks a pointer to method. Second `std::bind()` will not make a function pointer.

Comment: Agreed. My terminology was very loose. I'll edit to correct the wording.