# c++ pass child class method to base class method in argument

Tags: c++

I have a base class which has a method that takes a method pointer (class function pointer) as an argument. I derive a child class from this base class. I then want to pass a method of the child class to the method of the base class.

An example:

```
    class Base1
    {
        public:
             void BaseMethod(void (Base1::*basemth)(/*arguments list A*/), 
                             double a)){/*definition*/}
    };
    class Derived1 : public Base1
    {
        public: 
             void ChildMethod(/*arguments list A*/)

             void ChildMethod2()
             {
                double double_a = 1.0;
                void (Derived1::*pntr)(/*arguments list A*/);
                pntr = &Derived1::ChildMethod;
                BaseMethod(pntr, double_a); //<---- this fails
             }

    };
```

I get "error: no matching function for call to...".

Is this possible? If it is, what am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. I have looked at [child class method pointer to method parent argument c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568543/child-class-method-pointer-to-method-parent-argument-c) but following R Sahu's method does not seem to work, while Slava's answer does not seem relevant (I am not calling a child method from a parent instance).

Comment: Are those tick marks on line 5 accidental?  Also, what exactly is the complete error message text?

Comment: Agreed, if there is problem with whatever your error is (couldn't make sense of it,) then you are really going to have issues with the lines to follow.

Comment: Yes, the code included here is an example. I do apologise if the design is ugly @Ed Heal - I have not had a formal training in OOP. The actual error message is :"error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived1::Loop(void (Derived1::*&)(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, double>&), std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, double>&, int, int, int, int)’
     BaseMethod(pntr, sq, args, zno - 2, xno - 2, yno - 2, 0);" where "sq, args, zno - 2, xno - 2, yno - 2, 0" are the arguments I mentioned earlier.

Comment: The tick marks are accidental, yes (first post mishap) @donjuedo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

It is possible and should work ok if you use a `virtual` member function. If you use a non-virtual member function, it won't work.

Example program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base1
{
   public:

      void BaseMethod(void (Base1::*basemth)(), double a)
      {
         (this->*basemth)();
      }

      virtual void Method2() = 0;

};

class Derived1 : public Base1
{
   public: 

      void Method2()
      {
         std::cout << "In Derived1::Method2()\n";
      }

      void ChildMethod2()
      {
         double double_a = 1.0;
         BaseMethod(&Base1::Method2, double_a);
      }

};

int main()
{
   Derived1 d;
   d.ChildMethod2();
}
```

Output:

```
In Derived1::Method2()
```

Comment: @R Sahu I have seen your comment and I am trying it out now. Please give me a couple of minutes

Comment: @R Sahu, genius. It worked. I was declaring the virtual method as a child method, whereas you highlighted I should have been declaring it as a parent method. Many thanks!

Comment: Many thanks to Ed Heal, donjuedo and Evan Carslake for looking at my question and asking useful questions as well